# How to authenticate Google Calendar API on device with no input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I am developing a smart mirror app that shows events from a Google calendar. The smart mirror has no input device. I was hoping to use the [OAuth 2.0 for TV and Limited-Input Device Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/limited-input-device) workflow but the Calendar API is [not an allowed scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/limited-input-device#allowedscopes) for this flow. The application is a Python app running on a Raspberry Pi. Is there a correct way to achieve this authentication?

Comment: For the Google 0Auth Side of things, i think that it is really black and white towards that. I will suggest that you can take advantage that you are using a Raspberry Pi by discovering other OS that can support the application you are looking to create. Also if you can edit your question to highlight the workflow of your overall project as the current information included on your post does not provide clear guidelines how much work around can be recommended to you.